# Performance difference using `vector<bool>` vs `vector<uint8_t>`

Tags: c++, performance

I would like to ask a question that can be summarized in one sentence:

> What could be explanation for the performance difference between using `vector<bool>` (*slow*) and using `vector<uint8_t>` (*fast*)? (compiled with g++ 8.2 -O1 with C++17 standard)

Here is the full story.

It starts with LeetCode's [Count Primes](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-primes/) problem. Count the number of primes less than n.

One solution is to apply the Sieve of Eratosthenes, whose C++ code I will list below.

However, I interestedly noticed that with only one difference -- the `vector` type, there is a **consistent** gap in performance. Namely,

```
| type            | runtime |  memory |
|-----------------|---------|---------|
| vector<bool>    | 68 ms   | 8.6  MB |
| vector<uint8_t> | 24 ms   | 11.5 MB |
```

The full code is

```cpp
class Solution
{
public:
    int countPrimes(int n)
    {
        // vector<uint8_t> isprime(n, true);
        vector<bool> isprime(n, true);
        int res = 0, root = std::sqrt(n);
        for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
            if (isprime[i]) {
                ++res;
                if (i <= root)
                    for (int k = i * i; k < n; k += i)
                            isprime[k] = false;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

For your reference, LeetCode has the following note for C++ compilation

> Compiled with g++ 8.2 using the latest C++ 17 standard.
>
> Your code is compiled with level one optimization (-O1). AddressSanitizer is also enabled to help detect out-of-bounds and use-after-free bugs.
>
> Most standard library headers are already included automatically for your convenience.

My question is: **what could be the explanation for the observation that using `vector<bool>` is much slower (68 ms, 60% percentile) than using `vector<uint8_t>` (24 ms, 95% percentile)?**

*I repeated the experiment for more than 10 times. The difference in memory usage is also consistent. If you have any explanation for that (`vector<uint8_t>` uses more memory than `vector<bool>`), I also would like to hear.*

Thank you very much!

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` can be specialized to use individual bits.

Comment: Remember that accessing whole bytes is faster than accessing individual bits. Also, have you tried `-O3`?

Comment: @Yashas I found a comment from a linked post, commented by David Schwartz, saying "Don't use vector<bool> if you're super-concerned about performance. It's required by the standard to be very space efficient, and that has a performance cost." I guess this is what you mean.

Comment: The standard allows `std::vector<bool>` to be specialized to make use of individual bits. Accessing a byte is fairly fast but to access individual bit, you need to perform additional bitwise operations. You can find more information here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

Comment: It's not required by the standard to be more space efficient. It's implementation defined AFAIK.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 with a combination of your and Yashas' comments, it now becomes clear to me. `vector<bool>` can be made space-efficient, but at a cost of speed. Interesting, never knew it before! With `uint8_t` we are accessing the whole byte which is much more faster. Thanks!